# How to seperate the string part from the integer present in the string? For example Hell23ui 21 matt12 jac18

Tags: python, regex, extract

For example string is `Hell23ui 21 matt12 jac18`
should return a list with `[23,21,12,18]`
Basically Need to extract all numbers from string like above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to extract all numbers from the string and use `map` to convert them to `int`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Hell23ui 21 matt12 jac18'
>>> list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', s)))
[23, 21, 12, 18]
```

Comment: `finditer` is better if there are a lot of numbers in the string (full file content)